# JS inheritance - MDN article

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance, javascript-inheritance

given [MDN JS Inheritance article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance), we have these lines

[image]

My question is, why use Object.create and not just Person.prototype?
I understand the need to link prototypes.
But here is console example rendering the call to Object.create in fact not connecting the inherited methods:
[image]

Why is that? is it mistake in the article?

Comment: could you please replace the images of code by actual code

Comment: I agree that the the article is a bit confusing. It fails to explain that there are two things commonly known as “the prototype” of something. One is the `.prototype` property of a function, the other one is the prototype of an object (you can get this using `Object.getPrototypeOf`. The idea of the article is that `Object.getPrototypeOf(Teacher.prototype) === Person.prototype`, not that `Teacher.prototype === Person.prototype`. This is what `Object.create` does.

Comment: @vnt sorry, no. I would prefer answers from people who know it even without running the code(no offence, but i can run code on my own :) and if you know it without console - you REALLY KNOW IT)

Answer (score 4):

```
 Teacher.prototype = Person.prototype
```

That sets the prototye of the teachers to *the same object* as the persons prototype. So if you change that:

```
Teacher.prototype.hi = () => alert("hi");
```

Then that exists both on teachers and persons:

```
new Person().hi();
```

Thats not what you want when creating a subclass. If you do

```
Teacher.prototype = Object.create( Person.prototype );
```

You create *a new object that inherits* the persons prototype. Now the properties do not exist on the object itself, but they are inherited. That `getOwnPropertyNames` returns nothing does not mean that the properties are not inherited but the opposite: They just don't exist on the object itself, but on its parent.

```
 new Teacher().greeting();  // works :)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with `Teacher.prototype = Person.prototype` is that then, there is no actual inheritence going on - both prototypes will reference the same object. If you proceed to add a function to Teacher's prototype, for example `getClassTaught()`, that will mutate `Person.prototype`, which should not have that method.

```js
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
Person.prototype.getName = function() { return this.name; };
function Teacher(name, className) {
  this.name = name;
  this.className = className;
}
Teacher.prototype = Person.prototype;
Teacher.prototype.getClassTaught = function() { return this.className; };

const person = new Person();
console.log('getClassTaught' in person);
```

You also wouldn't be able to shadow `Person` functions without replacing them entirely. For example, if there's a `greeting()` function on `Person.prototype`, and you assign another `greeting()` function to `Teacher.prototype`, you'll be overwriting the function on `Person.prototype` - other `person`s calling `greeting()` may not work anymore, because the function is now Teacher-specific, rather than Person-generic.

```js
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
Person.prototype.getName = function() { return this.name; };
Person.prototype.greeting = function() { return 'Hi, I am ' + this.name; };
function Teacher(name, className) {
  this.name = name;
  this.className = className;
}
Teacher.prototype = Person.prototype;
Person.prototype.greeting = function() { return 'Hi, I am Teacher ' + this.name; };

const person = new Person('Bob');
console.log(person.greeting());
```

`getOwnPropertyNames` only shows you the property names *directly on the object itself* - it does not show *inherited* property names. When you use `Object.create(Person.prototype)`, `greeting` is *inherited* from the `Person` prototype; it's not directly on `Teacher.prototype`, so it doesn't show up in `getOwnPropertyNames`.

Comment: Thanks!!! I get it now. But what about the 'greeting' not shown on own methods for Teacher(and shown for Person)?